# how to remove duplicate value in result?

Tags: python

```
def number_of_cases(list_data):                     

    i=0
    j=0
    for j in range (len(list_data)):
        for i in range(len(list_data)):
            sum_list = list_data[i] + list_data[j]
            result = print(sum_list, end=' ')
    return result

def main():

    result=number_of_cases(['a','b','a'])
```

I don't want duplicate results.. how to remove the duplicated values in result.

result: aa ba aa ab bb ab aa ba aa

Comment: Your output will have no duplicates if you remove duplicates from the input. So you could use something like this: `unique_data = set(list_data); print([a+b for a in unique_data for b in unique_data])`

Answer (score 0):

```
result = list(set(result))
```

Will remove duplicates (since a set has only unique values) and then return a list like you already have.

Comment: 1) If this answer were accurate, it would be an extremely common duplicate. 2) It's not accurate. `result` is `None`.